# floating uiview subview disappears on scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UIView` that gets added to my `UITableView`.view as a subview.  It looks great and works fine, but when I scroll on my `UITableView`, the subview gets chopped up and disappears but only part of it (mostly the part that scrolls off).  I can get it to come back on by calling:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.myView];
```

but I'd rather not have to call this whenever the `UITableView` scrolls.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

[image: disappearing uiview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) { 
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you end goal is but adding a subview to `UITableView` is kind of counter intuitive. The `UITableView` manages it's subviews (`UITableViewCell`'s) and they are probably taking precedence over your subview. Are you looking for `backgroundView`?

Comment: basically i want a view to hover over the tableview...i'm actually adding it to the UIView and not the actual tableview.

Comment: Is that a `UITableViewController`? If so `self.view` is the `UITableView`

Comment: If this is the case then you may need to use a `UIViewController` subclass instead and add back in the `UITableViewController` functionality. The [overview for UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a quick run down of what `UITableViewController` does

Comment: I ended up not using a UITableView Controller and UIViewController instead to avoid the scrolling...thanks for your help though.